# How do I send an email with filled subject and email address?

Tags: android

I wrote an activity to send an email in the app. However, i can't find a way to set the recipient and subject in the edittext fill. How should I set the email at the beginning ??

my activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_feedback_email);

    emailAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    emailSubject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subject);
    message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
    sendEmailButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_button);

    sendEmailButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String toemailAddress = emailAddress.getText().toString();
            String msubject = emailSubject.getText().toString();
            String mmessage = message.getText().toString();

            Intent emailApp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailApp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{toemailAddress});
            emailApp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, msubject);
            emailApp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mmessage);
            emailApp.setType("message/rfc822");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailApp, "Send Email Via"));

        }
    });
}
```

my xml file

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Subject"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/subject"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:hint="Subject"
    android:inputType="text" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    android:text="To"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/email"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Message:"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:hint="Your message here..."
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/email" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/send_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#498b24"
    android:paddingTop="50dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Send Message "
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="46dp" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How should I set the email at the beginning ??

I am not sure if this is what you want but you can set it in the xml as `android:text="example@gmail.com"` For example:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:text="example@gmail.com"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
```